Best practices for taking an SSN or any other PII as input and storing it in salesforce
Just curious what are the options and considerations for accepting SSN or any other PII on a salesforce Omnistudio form or a ScreenFlow, Is it best to have it masked with Data mask or have the field as encrypted or both? and how what type of input should it be?

Depends on what your security requirements are. If you need to grant access to a full sandbox that contains a copy of production data to third-party personel, for example, you could not copy data over to that sandbox, or use Salesforce Data Mask (but Data Mask is a separate product, so you have to pay for it).
Masking sandbox data is different from securing fields on a production org. You could encrypt some custom fields which contain this kind of sensitive information in production. But then you have to take into consideration the limitations and implementation notes of encrypted fields, such as that when you have the View Encrypted Data permission, if someone logs in with your user (e.g: an admin logs in as you) they'll be able to view encrypted data because your user does. These fields can't be unique, or external ID, or have default values either. Also encrypted fields are editable regardless of whether the user has the View Encrypted Data permission (the information can be overwritten, as long as the user has update permission on the object and on that specific field).
While data is in transit within your flow or Apex, it will be unmasked and visible to your code/flow, and that can't be stopped, but you can at least - for Apex - remove any debug statement that might show the data on logs.
As for screen flows, it is up to you. The person who is typing the PII already knows its value, so I'd say it is pointless to worry too much about masking it. But if you want to give an extra feel of safety, there's the Password input field for flows:

